# Keras LSTM error: Input from layer reshape is incompatible with layer lstm

Tags: keras, rapidminer

Using RapidMiner I want to  implement an LSTM to classify patternes in a time series. Input data is a flat table. My first layer in the Keras operator is a core reshape from exampleset_length x nr_of_attributes to batch x time-steps x features. In the reshape parameter I specifically enter three figures because I want a specific amount of features and time-steps. The only way to achieve this is to specify also batch size, so in total three  figures. But when I add a RNN LSTM layer an error is returned: Input is incompatible with layer lstm expected ndim=n found ndim=n+1. What’s wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When specifying 'input_shape' for the LSTM layer, you do not include the batch size.

So your 'input_shape' value should be (timesteps, input_dim).

[Source: Keras RNN Layer, the parent layer for LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#rnn)

Comment: Your answer is in conformance with the Keras documentation. 
However, the Reshape operator in RapidMiner includes an validation. If input_shape and output of the Reshape are not of the same size then the following error is displayed: "Execution of Python script failed. ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged." To get rid of this error the only option is to Reshape from N x M to M x N. Such would result in an amount of time-steps equivalent to the amount of examples in the initial exampleset. That is not what I want.